# Use string variable content as label ID to update label.Text, I get error - 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

Tags: c#, string, label

C# newbie so be gentle!  Here is the code creating a string using the arguments from a button to match a label id so I can update the labels text.

```
string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] {','});                    //Convert the buttons arguments to server/service variables
    string strServerName = commandArgs[0];
    string strServiceName = commandArgs[1];     
    string strLabelID = String.Format(strServerName + "_" + strServiceName + "_" + "Status");   //assign the strLabelID to the format: "servername_servicename_Status" for updating the label text
```

This works when used directly as the Label ID name is "serverx_spooler_Status"...

```
serverx_spooler_Status.Text = String.Format(strServiceName);    //update label text
```

This fails even though the value of "strLabelID" is "serverx_spooler_Status"...

```
strLabelID.Text = String.Format(strServiceName);    //update label text
```

Thank you Derek for the direction to search into! The solution was this...

```
 // Find control on page.
    Control myControl1 = FindControl(strLabelID);
    Label myLabel1 = (Label)myControl1;
    myLabel1.Text = "Updated Label Text!";
```

Comment: is this WinForms, WPF, or ASP.net you are working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string service = "winmgmt";
        string server = "DFS5600";
        string labelText = string.Format("{0}_{1)_Status", server, service);

        foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr is Label)
            {
                if (ctr.Name == labelText)
                {
                    ctr.Text = "Hello Label";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction! I made this work using the code (updated in my original post).

Comment: Great Stuff... I'll remember this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `serverx_spooler_Status` is possibly a `Label` (not shown in question) that has a `Text` field, so `serverx_spooler_Status.Text` is valid.

The type of `strLabelID` is `string` (first inclusion), which does not have a `Text` field, so access to `strLabelID.Text` is invalid

try:

```
strLabelID = String.Format(strServiceName);
```

This will change the value of `strLabelID` to that of `strServiceName` (essentially same as: `strLabelID = strServiceName;`)

If you actually want to update a label, you will need an object of type `Label`, where you can access the `Text` field and update that (just lie you are doing with `serverx_spooler_Status`).  Your code inclusions do not show if you have any other label objects you could use.

Comment: So perhaps the question should be: How can I use a string variable to access the Label?

Comment: There is no easy way: you can find the label via reflexion or create a mapping of sorts (e.g. a hash table) that links the names to the label objects and look up the proper label based on the string

Comment: String.Format(strServiceName); doesn't do anything

Comment: It returns the value of `strServiceName` (as long as there are no substrings that can be interpreted as special formatting placeholders) -- hence my "essentialy" comment

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for :-

Label.Text = String.Format("{0}_{1}_Status",strServerName,strServiceName);

That should work.

Or you could say :-

string strLabelID = String.Format("{0}_{1}_Status",strServerName,strServiceName);

label1.Text = strLabelID;

Not quite sure what you mean. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use the variables sent from the button click ("servername", "servicename") appended with "_Status" as the Label ID (the label ID name is "servername_servicename_Status"). So rather than hard coding the Label ID and having to repeat the code, the Label ID can be pulled form the variables sent to the handler when the button is clicked. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help.

What you will need to do is loop through all labels in your project until you find a match like this :-

string strLabelID = String.Format("{0}_{1}_Status",strServerName,strServiceName);

foreach ( Control ctr in this.Controls)
{

if (ctr is Label)
    {
          if (ctr.Name == strLabelID)
                 {
                     //Do what ever in here
                 }
     }
}